# For what variable $a$ are vectors linearly independent?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have vectors $(1, a, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, a)$. For which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ are vectors linearly independent?
I tried to calculate it like matrix $$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&2&0\\
  a&1&2&0\\
1&1&a&0
\end{array}
\right] $$
After substracting rows it is
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&2&0\\
  0&1-a&2a-2&0\\
0&0&a-2&0
\end{array}
\right] $$
Then $(a-2)z=0$ etc.
I will get some equations, but I don't know how should I continue. Without determinant.

Comment: Then you could take the determinant, for example.

Comment: Yes, but I need to calculate it without knowing the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyze your reduced matrix.
Also, we can see that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & a \end{pmatrix} \sim  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1-a & 0 \\0 & 0 & a-2\end{pmatrix} $$
Since with the matrix totally reduced, no row vanishes for values $a\not=1,2$ the set is linearly independent for all $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @juraj You're welcome!